# Quotient then abelianize versus abelianize then quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

In one of our lectures for a course, my professor assumed something which is not obvious to me. Or at least, the proof is not obvious to me.

> Let $G$ be a group, $S$ a subset. Denote $\langle S \rangle ^G$ the subgroup normally generated by $S$, i.e. $\langle S \rangle ^ G =$ the subgroup generated by $ \{ g^{-1}sg : g \in G, s \in S\}$. If we quotient $G$ by $\langle S \rangle ^G$ and then abelianize, do we get (up to isomorphism) the same group obtained by abelianizing $G$ and then quotienting by $\langle \{ \varphi_G(x): x \in S\} \rangle$, where $\varphi_G:G \to G_{\mathrm{ab}}$ is the natural homomorphism?

I wish I could give some commentary but this is my first time handling most of these things. It would help to label everything: let $\varphi_G:G \to G_{ab}$ be the natural homomorphism, $q:G \to G/\langle S \rangle^G$ the quotient map, $p:G_{ab} \to G_{ab}/\langle \varphi_G(S) \rangle$ the quotient map, and $\varphi_{G/\langle S \rangle^G} :G/\langle S \rangle^G \to (G / \langle S \rangle^G)_{ab}$ the natural homomorphism. Then my question is, how do we know $G_{ab}/\langle \varphi_G(S) \rangle$ is $(G / \langle S \rangle ^G)_{ab}$?

Comment: I don't think that the quotient $G_{ab}/\langle S\rangle_{ab}$ is well-defined

Comment: $\langle S\rangle$ should be the subgroup *generated* by the set you give, not the set you give. That set is not, in general, a subgroup. I mean, $S$ itself is not given as a subgroup.

Comment: “Abelianize then take the quotient” is not taking the quotient modulo the abelianization of $\langle S\rangle$ (and “$\langle S_{\rm ab}\rangle$” doesn’t even make sense: $S$ is a subset, not a subgroup, you can’t “abelianize” a subset). It means looking at the image of $\langle S\rangle$ in $G^{\rm ab}$ and then taking the quotient modulo *that*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Per your first comment; I forgot to type 'generated by', I believe now it is fixed. Per your second comment: by $S_{\mathrm{ab}}$, I mean the set $\{ \varphi_{G}(x) : x \in S \}$. Then that is a subset of $G_{\mathrm{ab}}$. I think your last sentence in your second comment is saying exactly this.

Comment: Your description of what you call $\langle S\rangle$  (terrible notation; that normally means the subgroup generated; the normal subgroup generated is usually denoted $H^G$, so in this case, $\langle S\rangle^G$) is still incorrect.It is *not* the set you describe. The normal subgroup generated by $S$ is the **subgroup generated** by the set $\{gsg^{-1}\mid g\in G, s\in S\}$, not *equal* to that set as you assert in the post. As to what you meant by $S_{\rm ab}$, yes, that is what you want, but I know nobody who uses *that* notation, so it would be hard to guess without an explanation.

Comment: If $N$ is any normal subgroup of $G$, then $(G/N)_{\rm ab} = (G/N)/[G/N,G/N] \cong G/([G,G]N)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I've corrected everything in my post.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, what is the latter group being quotiented by? Is $([G:G]N)$ the normal subgroup generated by $\{ [g,g]n : g \in G, n \in N\}$? (Is the 'generated by' superfluous?)

Comment: @DerekHolt I've figured it out. Thank you!