# Quotients between groups and their abelianizations commute

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, quotient-group

This is a follow-up to [an earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052904/quotient-then-abelianize-versus-abelianize-then-quotient), although my question here is self-contained.

Let $G$ be a group, $S$ a subset of $G$. Denote $\langle S \rangle _G$ the normally-generated subgroup generated by $S$, i.e. the subgroup generated by $\{ g^{-1}sg : s \in S, g \in G\}$. Also, denote $Q=G/\langle S \rangle _G$.

Now let's name some maps:

- Let $\varphi_G$ be the quotient map from $G$ to $G_{\mathrm{ab}}$
- Let $q_S$ the quotient map from $G$ to $Q$
- Let $\varphi_Q$ be the quotient map from $Q$ to $Q_{\mathrm{ab}}$
- Let $p_S$ be the quotient map from $G_{\mathrm{ab}}$ to $G_{\mathrm{ab}}/ \langle \{\varphi_G(x):x \in S \} \rangle $.

Per the comments in the linked post:

> We have $Q_{\mathrm{ab}}=(G/\langle S \rangle _G)_{\mathrm{ab}}=(G/\langle S \rangle _G)/[G/\langle S \rangle _G:G/\langle S \rangle _G] \cong G/([G:G]\langle S \rangle _G)$. This is equal to (isomorphic to?) $(G/[G:G])/\langle \{ \varphi_G(x) : x \in S\}\rangle = G_{\mathrm{ab}}/ \langle \{ \varphi_G(x) : x \in S \} \rangle $.

In words, we have that the codomain of $p_S \circ \varphi_G$ is isomorphic to the codomain of $\varphi_Q \circ q_S$.

**My question is** whether the diagram with $G, Q, G_{\mathrm{ab}}, Q_{\mathrm{ab}}$ and the above maps is commutative. That is, we do we have $p_S \circ \varphi_G = \varphi_Q \circ q_S$? (I'm not certain my question is well-defined, since I've only shown the codomains are isomorphic--does it even make sense then to ask whether those two compositions are 'equal' if the codomains are not exactly equal?)

Comment: I think you mean "codomain". "Terminal object" is completely different.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you for clarifying that

Comment: The standard notation for the normal closure of $S$ in $G$  is $\langle S \rangle^G$ or $\langle S^G \rangle$. The subgroup $\langle S \rangle_G$ is the core of $\langle S \rangle$ in $G$, that is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ that is contained in $\langle S \rangle$.

Comment: @DerekHolt So to make sure I understand: what I have here written $\langle S \rangle_G$ is usually denoted $\langle S \rangle ^G$, correct?

Comment: That's right. For a subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H^G$ denotes the normal closure of $H$ in $G$. I have the impression that this subset $S$ is not particuarly relevant to your questions, and is acting as a distraction. Wny not just denote $\langle S \rangle^G$ by $N$, and then you can forget about $S$? So $N$ is just a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think that would be a productive way to approach my problem. Then the maps I'm trying to show are equal (i.e. that the diagram commutes) become a little simpler (in particular, the map $p_S$). These questions come as spin-offs as a problem given by my professor. He got us to work with $\langle S \rangle ^G$, but it almost surely can just be replaced by an $N$. Unfortunately, he is the most unapproachable man I've ever met, so I won't be asking him!

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok, say I consider an arbitrary normal $N$ in place of $\langle S \rangle^G$. Then what is/how do we notate the analog of $\langle \{ \varphi_G(x) : x \in S \} \rangle$?

Comment: That would just be $\varphi_G(N)$.